# Installing a flask application in development mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have followed flask's tutorial to the point of installing the flaskr blog (here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/install/). I'm new to installing python packages and I would appreciate some explanation of what's going on:

The tutorial says that installing the flaskr project has the benefit of being able to run it from anywhere.

However, I still can't run it outside the flask-tutorial directory (if I do `flask run` outside the flask-tutorial directory in the command line, I get `flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "flaskr".`)

Also, while I can import flaskr when working in the python interpreter, I also can't run it from there (even when I'm in the flask-tutorial directory):

```
import flaskr
app = flaskr.create_app()
app.run()
```

I get the following, and the python interpreter exits:

```
* Serving Flask app "flaskr" (lazy loading)
* Environment: development
* Debug mode: on
* Restarting with stat
/Users/user/projects/flask-tutorial/venv/scripts/python.exe can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

--- UPDATE:

If I set `$env:FLASK_ENV = "production"`, and then start the python interpreter, I can run flaskr successfully as described above.

However, still no luck running flaskr directly from the command line (with `flask run`) outside of the flask-tutorial directory.

Answer (score -1):

You are unable to use it outside the project folder because you have installed it in editable mode (`-e` flag). Uninstall the package and install again without the `-e` switch, so that it will be installed globally on your system. After that, it should work.

Comment: So if this doesn't have anything to do with the mode of installation, could it be that the installation itself didn't work properly? What else could have gone wrong?